# Adding Company Field to Customer Registration Field? Magento 2.1

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-account

I want to add a company field to the customer registration form, but i can not find the backend option for it. Is there a way i can do it programmatically?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try this script.

```
<?php
namespace Mynamespace\Modulename\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Module\Setup\Migration;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * Customer setup factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;
    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }
    /**
     * Installs DB schema for a module
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @return void
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();

        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $entityTypeId = $customerSetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY);
        $customerSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "company");

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "company",  array(
            "type"     => "varchar",
            "backend"  => "",
            "label"    => "company",
            "input"    => "text",
            "source"   => "",
            "visible"  => true,
            "required" => true,
            "default" => "",
            "frontend" => "",
            "unique"     => false,
            "note"       => ""

        ));

        $company   = $customerSetup->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "company");

        $company = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'company');
        $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
        $used_in_forms[]="checkout_register";
        $used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
        $used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";
        $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_checkout";
        $company->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
            ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
            ->setData("is_system", 0)
            ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
            ->setData("is_visible", 1)
            ->setData("sort_order", 100);

        $company->save();



        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working. And you're creating a new attribute, but i need to use the existing one...

Comment: Is there a working solution now?

Comment: @Radosav there is no out of the box solution for it, Company field is only added to the customer_address entity type not customer, so you have to create custom attribute for it to work on customer entity type.

Answer (score -1):

This should be an easy and taken as a serious inquiry.  Additional customer registration data is key for sorting and marketing to different customer groups.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. I would request to please explain a bit more so that the answer can benefit someone.